# The Integers in the ArrayList are added by 48

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this method:

```
public ArrayList Arraylistify(){
     for(int x = 0; x < value.length(); x++){
         if(Character.getNumericValue(value.charAt(x)) >= 10 && Character.getNumericValue(value.charAt(x)) <= 26){
             for(char y = 'A'; y < 'Z'; y++){
                 if(Character.toString(y).equalsIgnoreCase(Character.toString(value.charAt(x)))){
                     numbers.add(Character.getNumericValue(y));
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
          numbers.add((int) value.charAt(x));
     }
     return numbers;
}
```

That's supposed to take characters from the string value(which would only contain numbers and letters) and put them into an ArrayList(converting the letters into their numerical value). So if the string was 4567A, the ArrayList would contain a 4, a 5, a 6, a 7, and a 10, in that order. However, all the Integers in the ArrayList are added by 48. What's causing this? How do I fix this? Should I choose a different method of doing this? Please reply. Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII...

Comment: I think you're getting ASCII values of your character numbers.

Comment: I would appear you're trying to convert hexadecimal to integer (sort of ...). That ... wouldn't be how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 public static List<Integer> toList(String value) {
     List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
     for(char ch: value.toCharArray())
        list.add(Character.getNumericValue(ch));
     return list;
 }
```